# model associations between movies, actors, directors... etc in CakePHP

Tags: database-design, cakephp, associations, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to figure out the best way to set up my tables/model associations.

I have a table of `movies`.  Each Movie could have zero or many Actors, Directors, Publishers, Writers... etc.

I can set it up just fine if I use different tables/models for each type of person... but that seems unclean.

My thought is to use a `People` model/table, with a HABTM to `PeopleType` and HABTM to `Movie`.

This would work just fine to link specific people to a movie, but... what about people like Clint Eastwood - he'd be a director for one movie, an actor for another, and maybe even both.  How would the movie know which type it's referring to?

Just can't wrap my head around the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way you can do:

```
people_types (id, name)
people_details (id, first_name, last_name, ....)
people (id, person_details_id, person_type_id)
movies_people(id, person_id, movie_id) 
movies (id, title, ...)
```

Comment: Why would this be better than the same thing minus the "people_details" table?  I'm confused why I would keep the details separate from the people table - seems overkill?

Comment: Because Clint Eastwood is an actor and a director. If you do not use `people_details` table in this example you would need to have `first_name` and `last_name` columns in `people` table. So, you would have two Clint Eastwoods rows with fully identical `first_name` and `last_name` columns - one as the actor, another as the director. That would be data duplication.

Comment: Ah!  I think this one makes sense / seems good.  So there WOULD be duplication in the `people` table, but only duplication of links (ids) to the `people_details` table, and not of actual data, right?  This one makes more sense to me.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Ended up going with people_types, people_details, people_details_people_types (has movie_id in this)

Answer (score 1):

<s>As a person can be the director in one movie and the actor in another movie your approach of using 'people type' does not seems good as your `people` table would contain duplicate information for every person belonging to multiple types.</s> I would create a table `people_details` and specific tables for every type `directors`, `actors`, `publishers` etc. with foreign keys to `people_details` table. `directors`, `actors`, `publishers` tables would also contain any columns specific only to the corresponding type of people.

To summarize, `Actor` belongsTo `PersonDetails`, `Director` belongsTo `PersonDetails`, `Actor` HABTM `Movie`, `Director` HABTM `Movie`.

Comment: Either I'm not understanding you, or you misunderstood what I said.  In my example, there would be no duplication in the people table.  The HABTM table "people_people_types" would contain a "person_id" and a "people_type_id" which would like a person to 1 or more people_types.  Also - can you clarify why you think it'd be better to have a table for every people-type when they all have the same data?  This seems like more duplication than anything mentioned thus-far.  In your example, wouldn't someone like Clint Eastwood take up a spot in 2 different tables (or more?)

Comment: I misunderstood you. But nevertheless my answer is valid. It is better to have a table for every type because of simplicity of implementation and understanding. There would be no duplication because any duplicate (among different people-types) columns should be in `people_details` table. Clint Eastwood details would be in `people_details` table. `actors` table would have a record with `person_details_id` referring to id of Clint Eastwood in `people_details` table. `directors` table would have a record with `person_details_id` referring to id of Clint Eastwood in `people_details` table.

Comment: So, no data duplication, only foreign keys. Take a look at http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html#MapEachClassToTable

Comment: Ok... so I finally wrapped my head around what you're telling me to do - and obviously someone else likes your answer (+1 rating) - can you try explaining one more time why this is better, since this will add 6-8 extra tables in my database, it seems backwards logic to me.

Comment: I provided you one of data mapping strategies. You can find more if you follow the link I provided above. You will find a table listing advantages and disadvantages of each strategy there. The one I described is called "One table per class". In order to answer your question "why this is better" I need to know the workable solution to compare to. Better than what?

Comment: I read the text you sent - it explains how, but I see nowhere that it mentions why this is the way to go over other options.  The comparison is the answer by "corsen" - using the details I listed in my post with the slight addition of one field.

Comment: There is no single correct answer to your question. You can achieve what you want by different ways. You would decide yourself which method to use. Maintaining modified (by adding an extra column) join table `movies_people` is complicated in Cakephp.

Comment: I can think of ~200 ways to get this done - what I'm looking for is not just "here's one way", but instead for someone's explanation of why they think X way is better than Y and Z ways.

Comment: Every method has its own advantages and disadvantages. It is difficult to answer which one is the best having limited information because it depends on the project. Using this method you would have more tables but they would be smaller. Using another method you would have less tables but they would be larger. What is better for you project? It depends on how many movies you will have in your database, your database size. For a larger database I would use the method with more tables. For a smaller database - the method with less tables.

Comment: Actually it also depends on what columns you have now in `people` table. If there are any columns related only to one `people_type` I would not want to have `NULL` values for every other person type.

Answer (score 0):

In your join table:
movies_people

You could add a extra field for something like "role".  Where you would specific the persons function in that movie.  Then you can add Client Eastwood into the join table twice, once for each role he has in the production of that movie.

Comment: would "role" be just a string, or an id for the 'people_types' ?

Comment: I would probably rename people_types to role since it is confusing that a person can act as more than one people_type.  Role seems to make more sense if I am understanding your problem correctly.  A person can assume 0 or many roles in a movie production.

Comment: I guess my question is more about associations than field name.  Should the "role" field be the id of the type of person, or a string?  (I assume it should be the ID)